# How to compile an edited java file into a class class file that's a part of a package [Related to Minecraft]

Tags: java, class, jar, compilation

So I have am trying to edit a class file that is in a .jar file (the .jar file has a few other classes but I am only trying to edit this one). I used the source .java for this specific class and I am having trouble compiling it into a class, because the compiler calls errors because it is calling things from the package.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Alternatively, it would be really helpful if someone knew of a program that would allow me to directly edit the code of a .class file in a .jar file without all the decompiling and recompiling.

Extra information

1. The .jar file is a Minecraft mod I'm whipping up for a friend.
2. Code of original .class (which works):

   ```
   package pw.cinque.cpsmod;
   import cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
   import cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;
   import cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent$ClientTickEvent;
   import net.minecraftforge.client.event.MouseEvent;

   import cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
   import cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;
   import net.minecraftforge.client.event.MouseEvent;
   import pw.cinque.cpsmod.CPSMod;

   public class ClickListener
   {
     public ClickListener() {}

     private boolean hasClickedThisTick = false;

     @cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent
     public void onMouse(MouseEvent event) {
       if (button != 0) {
         return;
       }

       if ((CPSMod.preventDoubleclicks) && (buttonstate) && (hasClickedThisTick)) {
         event.setCanceled(true);
         return;
       }

       if (buttonstate) {
         hasClickedThisTick = true;
         CPSMod.addClick();
       }
     }

     @cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent
     public void onClientTick(cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent.ClientTickEvent event) {
       hasClickedThisTick = false;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Code of file I edited:

   ```
   package pw.cinque.cpsmod;

   import cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
   import cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;
   import cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent$ClientTickEvent;
   import net.minecraftforge.client.event.MouseEvent;

   import cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
   import cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;
   import net.minecraftforge.client.event.MouseEvent;
   import pw.cinque.cpsmod.CPSMod;

   public class ClickListener {
       private boolean hasClickedThisTick = false;
       int newVar = 0;
       @SubscribeEvent
       public void onMouse(MouseEvent event) {
           if (event.button != 0) {
               return;
           }
           if (CPSMod.preventDoubleclicks && event.buttonstate && this.hasClickedThisTick) {
               event.setCanceled(true);
               return;
           }
           if (event.buttonstate) 
           {
               this.hasClickedThisTick = true;
               CPSMod.addClick();
               newVar = CPSMod.getClicks();            
               if(newVar > 5)
               {
       CPSMod.addClick();

       }
   }
   }

   @SubscribeEvent
   public void onClientTick(TickEvent.ClientTickEvent event) {
       this.hasClickedThisTick = false;
   }
   }
   ```
4. These are the error messages I get when I try to compile it.

> ```
> ClickListener.java:2: error: package cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler does not exist
>      import cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
>                                             ^
> ClickListener.java:3: error: package cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent does not exist
>      import cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;
>                                          ^
> ClickListener.java:4: error: package cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent does not exist
>      import cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent$ClientTickEvent;
>                                          ^
> ClickListener.java:5: error: package net.minecraftforge.client.event does not exist
>      import net.minecraftforge.client.event.MouseEvent;
>                                            ^
> ClickListener.java:7: error: package cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler does not exist
> import cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
>                                        ^
> ClickListener.java:8: error: package cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent does not exist
> import cpw.mods.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;
>                                     ^
> ClickListener.java:9: error: package net.minecraftforge.client.event does not exist
> import net.minecraftforge.client.event.MouseEvent;
>                                       ^
> ClickListener.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
> import pw.cinque.cpsmod.CPSMod;
>                        ^
>   symbol:   class CPSMod
>   location: package pw.cinque.cpsmod
> ClickListener.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
>     public void onMouse(MouseEvent event) {
>                         ^
>   symbol:   class MouseEvent
>   location: class ClickListener
> ClickListener.java:40: error: package TickEvent does not exist
>     public void onClientTick(TickEvent.ClientTickEvent event) {
>                                       ^
> ClickListener.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>     @SubscribeEvent
>      ^
>   symbol:   class SubscribeEvent
>   location: class ClickListener
> ClickListener.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
>     @SubscribeEvent
>      ^
>   symbol:   class SubscribeEvent
>   location: class ClickListener
> ClickListener.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
>         if (CPSMod.preventDoubleclicks && event.buttonstate && this.hasClickedThisTick) {
>             ^
>   symbol:   variable CPSMod
>   location: class ClickListener
> ClickListener.java:25: error: illegal start of type
>         if (event.buttonstate) {
>            ^
> ClickListener.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
>             CPSMod.addClick();
>             ^
>   symbol:   variable CPSMod
>   location: class ClickListener
> ClickListener.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
>       gay = CPSMod.getClicks();
>             ^
>   symbol:   variable CPSMod
>   location: class ClickListener
> ClickListener.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
>           CPSMod.addClick();
>           ^
>   symbol:   variable CPSMod
>   location: class ClickListener
> 17 errors
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile that class with all its dependencies, otherwise it will not work. Probably you should get all the files from that .jar, make the modifications you want and then compile and compress it again.